# How to drag opposite direction points of an anchor point simultaneously in photoshop cc?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, vector, pen-tool, anchor-point

I have an anchor point B selected on a shape created with pen tool as shown in the image

[image]

Given that 2*AB = BC. Now, whatever pen tool I use to drag C or A, it only changes BC or AB, not both of them. The only way I found is to use convert point tool, but the problem is it resets AB = BC.

**Question:** How to drag C and A, in opposite directions, simultaneously keeping ABC a straight line?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. If I understand correctly.

You can keep handles at 90/45° angles by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> as you drag a handle.

But, you simply can't drag two *different length* handles at the *same* time. The **only** way to drag more than one handle at a time is via the **Convert Anchor Point Tool** and *resetting* the symmetry of the handles.